# update with select result conditional takes too long

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
update A 
set step1_response='step2', 
    step1_editor='step2' 
where ch_idx in (select B.ch_idx 
                 from B 
                 where B.check_e_done_ct=B.check_e_tot_ct 
                   AND B.check_w_tot_ct=B.check_w_done_ct);
```

1. The result of select inside the parentheses is about 4000 rows.
2. The table to be updated (A) is about 90000 rows.

the command above takes forever to complete.
how can i re-write this query to get result faster?

thank you!

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Comment: I am not using upating multiplte tables though :(

Answer (score 2):

```sql
UPDATE a 
JOIN b USING (ch_idx)
SET a.step1_response='step2', 
    a.step1_editor='step2' 
WHERE b.check_e_done_ct = b.check_e_tot_ct 
  AND b.check_w_tot_ct = b.check_w_done_ct;
```

or maybe

```sql
UPDATE a
JOIN ( SELECT ch_idx
       FROM b
       WHERE b.check_e_done_ct = b.check_e_tot_ct 
         AND b.check_w_tot_ct = b.check_w_done_ct ) bb USING (ch_idx)
SET a.step1_response='step2', 
    a.step1_editor='step2';
```